# Fill php form --> upload file ---> send mail with attachment

Tags: php, file-upload, email-attachments

I know this question was asked several times, but I found no working answer.

As the title says, I have a php form with input file type, on submit, all data will be emailed including the file as attachment, why cant i find any working script.

Please help.

updating my answer

```
$fileatt  = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileatt_type = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'];
$fileatt_name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];


$subject = "Some Subject goes here";
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$fileatt_name."\"\r\n";
$headers .=  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";




    // create a boundary string. It must be unique
      $semi_rand = md5(time());
      $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

      // Add the headers for a file attachment
      $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                  " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

     if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
      // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary)
      $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
      $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
      fclose($file);

      // Base64 encode the file data
      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));  
     }
//begin of HTML message 
$message ="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                  "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
                  " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
                  //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                  $data . "\n\n" .
                  "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

Comment: There are many examples just by searching here on stackoverflow - [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+form+file+upload+and+email](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+form+file+upload+and+email)

Comment: [What have you tried??](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried PHP mail, I get a garbled message, no clear text no content

Comment: Stackoverflow works better when you post your code that you have tried, and then we can help walk you through how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't found it because you have not searched well.
Here, take this tutorial:

-Fill form and upload file using this:
http://www.9lessons.info/2012/04/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery.html
 -Use [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial) for adding attachment using this: [phpMailer attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322610/phpmailer-attachment)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but obviously you havent read my problem well.

Comment: @Digitalfortress : I just changed my answer

Comment: I think I'll have to use phpMailer, php mail doesnt work
THanks

Comment: It works gr8. The problem may be the smtp settings. As for mail attachment, the link to question is given.