# mail headers for uploading file in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to send a mail with HTML format data and excel sheet attachment. I can send the mail but it is not supporting HTML format data. This is my code:

```
<?php
$cmpy_name = $_POST["cmpy_name"];
$business = $_POST["business"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$mb_no = $_POST["mb_no"];
$no_emp = $_POST["no_emp"];
$emp_family = $_POST["emp_family"];
$insu_name = $_POST["insu_name"];
$insu_edate = $_POST["insu_edate"];
$exp_years = $_POST["exp_years"];
$insu_sum = $_POST["insu_sum"];
$insu_coverage= $_POST["insu_coverage"];

$count=count($insu_coverage);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
$coverage="$coverage$insu_coverage[$i], ";
}
$f_upload = $_POST["f_upload"];
$p_name = $_POST["p_name"];
$p_mail = $_POST["p_mail"];
$p_mb = $_POST["p_mb"];
$p_date = $_POST["p_date"];
$p_time = $_POST["p_time"];

$arr=array ($p_date,$p_time);//,$health_ap);
$g_time=implode(" ",$arr);

$p_auth = $_POST["p_auth"];

 $email_message .= "<html><body><table width='100%'>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Company Name</td><td>:</td><td>$cmpy_name</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Nature of business</td><td>:</td><td>$business</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Person Name</td><td>:</td><td>$name</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Mobile Number</td><td>:</td><td>$mb_no</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Nature of business</td><td>:</td><td>$no_emp</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Required for employee family members</td><td>:</td><td>$emp_family</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Previous insurance name</td><td>:</td><td>$insu_name</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Previous insurance expiry date</td><td>:</td><td>$insu_edate</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Claim experience in last three years</td><td>:</td><td>$exp_years</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Sum insured</td><td>:</td><td>$insu_sum</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Coverage</td><td>:</td><td>$coverage</td></tr>";

 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Personal Information</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Name</td><td>:</td><td>$p_name</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Email-ID</td><td>:</td><td>$p_mail</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Mobile Number</td><td>:</td><td>$p_mb</td></tr>";
 $email_message .= "<tr><td>Convinent time to contact</td><td>:</td><td>$g_time</td></tr>";
 $email_message.= "</table></body></html>";


$to = "sangeetha.lrl2014@gmail.com";
$fromEmail = "sangee.selvi@gmail.com"; 
$fromName = "lrl"; 
$subject = "Group mediclaim"; 

$mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');

/* GET File Variables */ 
$tmpName = $_FILES['f_upload']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['f_upload']['type']; 
$fileName = $_FILES['f_upload']['name']; 

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $fromName"; 

if(in_array($_FILES['f_upload']['type'],$mimes)){
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
  fclose($file); 

  /* a boundary string */
  $randomVal = md5(time()); 
  $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

  /* Header for File Attachment */
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n" ;
  $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 


  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
 $email_message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
 $email_message . "\n\n"; 

  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $email_message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
  "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
  $data . "\n\n" . 
  "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 
} 
 else {
  die("Sorry, mime type not allowed");
}
$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$email_message", "$headers"); 

if($flgchk){
  echo "A email has been sent to: $to";
 }
else{
  echo "Error in Email sending";
}
?>
```

Which header do I need to give to support both HTML format data and attachment?

Comment: You can look at this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322610/phpmailer-attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Content-Type: text/plain; to

> Content-Type: text/html;

at your first $email_message

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), which is much simple and easier for handling everything.

Answer (score 0):

maybe multipart/mixed ?

```
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";
```